# I have a problem with filter stopword operator in rapidminer

Tags: text-mining, rapidminer, rosette

I am working on a sentiment analysis project in Persian language and I use rapidminer to this purpose..

I installed the rosette extension for some text preproccesing purpose in this language such as tokenization.
I have a problem with filter stop word (dictionary) operator... when I apply this operator to my data set (after tokenization) I receive only tokenized data set without filtering stop words...

Do you know what is the cause of this problem?

[image]